# angularJs:store time in 00:00:00 format

Tags: angularjs

if I select a date from datepicker and save it into db means it is storing in 2018-05-21T18:30:00.000Z format. But I want to store the time in 00:00:00.000 format and date as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
new Date(new Date("your date").setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

```js
var dateObj = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
console.log(dateObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/), which is a library to easily handle dates. In your case, you could format the date using:

```
moment('your date').format('hh:mm:ss.SSS');
```

EDIT: Reading your question again, I am not sure what do you want to store, but if it's only the date, you can do it with moment as well.

Comment: req.body.activefrom && new Date(moment(req.body.activefrom)). If i add this code, by default it is storing selected date with current time. I donot want to store current time. So i want to update time as 00:00:00:00

Comment: Then you can convert the hour to the desired format using this: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

Answer (score 0):

You can use $filter to do the job.

in your ctrl, assuming the date is a proper Date instance

```
$scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')(dt,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

Of course you have to **inject** the $filter service.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using Java.Find the below code

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
         now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
         now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
         now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
         now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
String date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.mss").format(now.getTime());
```

Comment: But You have to convert the String date to Date while inserting into data base.

Comment: I’d be surprised if a Java answer could help the asker. In any case I discourage the use of `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is long outdated and also notoriously troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$filter` to the controller

Use the below function.

```
$filter('date')(dt,'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the official documentation there are two ways you can do that:

1) in your html page

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

2) in tour controller

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

see more on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date